# How would I write this statement in mathematical terms

Tags: calculus

I have a function $y(t)$ and an estimate of time at which the function is maximum $t_i$, I want the final estimate $t_f$ to be the value that makes $y(t)$ maximum in the interval
$t_i - n < t < t_i + n $.ie

$$
  t_f = \text{time that makes [max}\hspace{0.1cm} y(t) ]\hspace{0.1cm} \text{where t is in interval} \hspace{0.1cm} t_i - n < t_i < t_i + n
$$

How would I write this with using a proper mathematical statement?

Comment: Do you mean $t_i - n < t < t_i + n$?

Comment: Yes I meant to say that $t_i - n < t < t_i + n$,I will edit post.$n$ is a time interval, perhaps I should have used the variable $t_n$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the argmax notation, which lets you write your $t_f$ as 
$$ t_f = \mathop{\rm arg\,max}_{t \in (t_i - n, t_i + n)} y(t) $$
(read as "the argument which maximises $y$ in the interval ...")

Or you can just write: Let $t_f \in (t_i - n, t_i +n)$ be such that 
$$ y(t_f) = \max_{t \in (t_i -n, t_i +n)} y(t) $$

Comment: Thank you very much for this